# Trap a special click event on an Edit/Textbox control with C++/WinAPI/MFC

Tags: c++, winapi, textbox

I'm coding in C++/MFC on a Windows platform (using MS VS2008.) I have this Edit control (which is basically a text box) that is set to be read-only. The control displays some basic information. I want to add an "Easter Egg" to my app, i.e. when a user Ctrl+Shift clicks on this edit control it must display some additional info. The question is how to trap such a click event using MFC/native WinAPIs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straight forward way is to subclass the edit control using [`SetWindowLong`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633591%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and catch [`WM_LBUTTONDOWN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645607%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) event. You'd then want to call [`GetAsyncKeyState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or equivalent to check whether the specific key is being pressed or not, and show the message.

Comment: @ahmd0 You're welcome! btw, I forgot to say that you can catch `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` event and still check for key state. if you read the parameter sections of the article, it says you can simply read the value of `wParam` to get the key state.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to do subclassing. Just catch [`WM_PARENTNOTIFY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/inputmsg/wm-parentnotify)

```
case WM_PARENTNOTIFY: {
    if (LOWORD(wParam) == WM_LBUTTONDOWN)
        printf("x: %i, y: %i\n", LOWORD(lParam), HIWORD(lParam));
}
break;
```

By default, child windows in a dialog box have the `WS_EX_NOPARENTNOTIFY` style and so doesn't notify the parent window. You should remove this style.

```
case WM_INITDIALOG: {
    HWND hChildWnd = GetDlgItem(hWnd, IDC_CHILD);
    LONG style = GetWindowLong(hChildWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE);
    style &= ~WS_EX_NOPARENTNOTIFY;
    SetWindowLong(hChildWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, style);
    ...
```

P.S. I hope it's not too late :D