# winapi - detecting mouse button events over an edit control

Tags: winapi

I have a main window with a standard edit control. I would like to detect WM_LBUTTONDOWN and WM_LBUTTONUP events for an edit control. I can achieve it using subclassing or superclassing. Do you know an alternative way ? Maybe the main window receives some other events which allow to detect it ?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: "*I can achieve it using subclassing or superclassing*" - that is the correct way to go. "*Maybe the main window receives some other events which allow to detect it?*" - no, it does not. The only other option is a mouse hook via `SetWindowsHookEx()` or a UI hook via `SetWinEventHook()`

Comment: @RemyLebeau What about WM_PARENTNOTIFY ?

Comment: @Irbis good point, I forgot about that, since it is not a commonly used message. As long as the edit control is not created with the `WS_EX_NOPARENTNOTIFY` style, it should work.

Comment: Depending on what you are trying to do in response to those messages, `WM_PARENTNOTIFY` may be too late (the edit control would already handle that mouse button message).

Comment: You can refer to the answers of [Trap a special click event on an Edit/Textbox control with C++/WinAPI/MFC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10201469/trap-a-special-click-event-on-an-edit-textbox-control-with-c-winapi-mfc) question.